# People picker causes correlation ID when adidng audience to a navigation link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to add an audience (SP2010) to a link so that it only becomes visible to a certain audience. I can use the people picker and search for the audience fine when I add it and then submit I always get a correlation error. I have found the error in the ULS:

System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined.
 at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToXmlQualifiedName(String value, Boolean decodeName)
 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read1_Object(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read2_DictionaryEntry(Boolean checkType)
 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDictionaryEntryArray.Read3_ArrayOfDictionaryEntry()